# Cloud based alternative to LAMP that can communicate to external API's

Tags: php, json, parse-platform, lamp, apigee

I am developing PHP plugins for CMS systems that at the moment communicates with my LAMP (PHP server) setup. As I am about to rewrite my server and PHP plugins and I am looking for a way to bypass the server konfiguration, maintaining and so on.

The server receives JSON, saves information from the JSON to my MySQL database, creates new JSON calls to external API's handles the response, saves part of it to the database. Merges pdf files from the different API's and creates a final JSON response to the CMS plugins.

My questions is in regards to a big update of my modules; Is there a setup that allows me to disgard my LAMP setup and use a cloud service? I have looked at Apigee and Parse but I don't know if they can make external API calls and handle the response of the API's?

If this can be done is it using Node.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly Apigee can make outbound calls either through our policy based proxies or with a Node based proxy. Passivation of data can be accomplished through our KVM policies.

You can try it out with the free offering and see if it makes sense.

Comment: If the JSON must be altered and sent to another API will this be possible with KVM or will I need to program this using Node.js?

Comment: Modification of the request can be done using out of the box XML based policies or within a Javascript callout. If you prefer you can use Python or Java on a paid account.

Comment: I don't quite get what you are saying. Can you elaborate on how I would program conditional statements in apigee? Eg how I would sent a JSON request to another server and sent the response from that server back to my user?

Comment: Within Edge you create flow configurations that control not only applying security checks to a request, but also can modify requests, select a target server to call with a request, mediate the payload before sending to the client. We have a lot of documentation on HOW this is done on the apigee web site. You should take a look at the training material there as the details are well beyond what would be appropriate for a SOF response. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So you want standard website hosting with a MySQL database?

Any web host can do this for you. They manage the server, handle updates, etc.  You just run your code in your little folder.  Setup your domain.  Connect to the database that they setup.

How much traffic are you doing?  Do you need a whole server?  A wee one or a giant one?  Failover? Backups?

You should also look into Application Hosting with one of the big providers if you are worried about scaling.

http://aws.amazon.com/application-hosting/

http://www.rackspace.com/saas

Comment: I would still have to worry about security, database queries and so on. I would like all of that work to be done by the cloud service.